# Problem with combining multiple excel files in python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am quite new to python programming. I need to combine 1000+ files into one file. each file has 3 sheets in it and I need to get data only from sheet2 and make an final excel file. I am facing a problem to pick a value from specific cell from each excel file on sheet2 and create a column. python is picking the value from first file and create a column on that

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame()
            
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsm'):
            df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=1, header=None) 
            df['REPORT_NO'] = df.iloc[1][4] #Report Number
            df['SUPPLIER'] = df.iloc[2][4] #Supplier
            df['REPORT_DATE'] = df.iloc[0][4] #Report Number
        df2 = df2.dropna(thresh=15)
        df2 = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        df = df.reset_index()
        del df['index']
    df2.to_excel('FINAL_FILES.xlsx')
```

How can I solve this issue so python can take from each excel and put the information on right rows.

Comment: I think what you want is df2 to be gloabl and df not to be.
Instead of doig this with a loop, do it with one file 1 and file 2, then do it with the output from  that and file 3. Somewhere in there I think your scoping is wrong, either with the external ` df = pd.DataFrame()` or your creation of a column entirely filled with the report no, supplier or report date.

Answer (score 0):

I `df.iloc[2][4]` refers to the 2nd row and 4th column of the 1st sheet. You have imported with `sheet_name=1` and never activated a different sheet, though you mentioned all of the `.xlsm` have 3 sheets.

II *your scoping could be wrong. Why define `df` outside of the loop? If will change per file, so no need for an external one. All info form the loop should be put into your `df2` before the next iteration of the loop.*

III Have you checked if  `append` is adding a row or a column?
Even though

```
df['REPORT_NO'] = df.iloc[1][4] #Report Number
df['SUPPLIER'] = df.iloc[2][4] #Supplier
df['REPORT_DATE'] = df.iloc[0][4] #Report Number
```

are written as columns they have Report Number/Supplier/Report Date repeated for every row in that column.

When you use `df2 = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)` check the output. It might not be appending in the way you intend.

Comment: Yes, as I only need the data from sheet_name=1 and in each excel sheet_name=1 at these position has supplier name in this cell.